# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: swift4, xcode9

Below is the source code MetaData and I can not get rid of that error.

How can I fix it?

Source code: MetaData:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `hashValue` on `commonKey`, this will result in an `Int` value. This expression is the LHS of an `??` operator whose RHS is a `String` value - so you have a type mismatch; and the whole expression is part of a `switch` where the `case` values are strings. Switching on a hash value is not usual.

Removing the `hashValue` will probably allow this to compile, but whether it will do what you intend we cannot say.

HTH

Comment: i removed the hashValue but it still gives me an error

Comment: "an error" is not very specific. More importantly *you* either (a) know what you are trying to switch on because you wrote the code, or (b) need to figure that out as you're debugging code someone else wrote. Once you know what you are trying to switch on, which is presumably some string value, you need to write the appropriate expression to obtain that value. If you get stuck ask a new question explains what you are trying to do, what you've tried, what went wrong, and some will undoubtedly help you. BTW paste code into your question, not screenshots, as this helps people trying to help you.

Comment: thank you, i got the code from github. I imported the source code to a new project, so it helped me  to solve the problem